# Casting optional values through a custom annotation class in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

I have a custom class I made to create customer pins on a map based on a JSON array. In addition to title, subtitle, and coordinate, I pull a unique identifier (discipline) from the array pass it along with the pin. The identifier is correctly getting created from the array, but I'm having issues with reading it in the next view controller. Despite the fact that it appears to be a String, It keeps getting printed as an optional whenever I try and print the identifier in the subsequent view controller.

For example, I can assign it the value "1", but if I try and print (or add it to another JSON POST), it keeps getting turned into "Optional(1)" despite trying to cast it as a String in all the places i can think of (It says the value is already a string). My JSON post is throwing an error because its not correctly populating the post string.

Any idea why this is still an optional? How do I cast it to a string when Xcode says it already is a string?

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String!
    let subtitle: String!
    let discipline: String!
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let image: UIImage!

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, discipline: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.discipline = discipline
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.image = UIImage(named: "Icon-40.png")

        super.init()
    }
```

Comment: where in you code did you find the issue? "Despite the fact that it appears to be a String, It keeps getting printed as an optional whenever I try and print the identifier in the subsequent view controller"

Comment: the problem is coming when I get a response from a JSON post to my server. I'm trying to put the disciple object into the post and because its optional, the server can't read it properly

Comment: please show us that part of your code ...

Comment: I figured out my problem. I accidentally set the value from the original JSON  response as `discipline: ("\(value)") as! String` instead of `discipline: (value) as String` Thanks for the pointers